# Passing TypedArray to New Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image

I have my OnCreate in which I use a TypedArray to store a list of files define in my strings.xml. I have an activity, showDetailActivity, which I want to pass these images through. How can I pass my TypedArray to my activity, showDetailActivity? I read about passing objects, in which I learnt objects must implement parceable in order to be passed through the intent. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TypedArray images;
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Resources res = getResources();
            myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

            images = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.pictures);

            itemAdapter ItemAdapter = new itemAdapter(this, images);
            myListView.setAdapter(ItemAdapter);

            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Intent showDetailActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                    showDetailActivity.putExtra("com.malcolmtanti.listapp.INDEX", i);

                    //pass TypedArray Here
                    startActivity(showDetailActivity);
                }
            });
```

}

Comment: you don't edit your `TypedArray images;`, you only load it from resources. Why can't you just load it from resources in new activity?

Comment: I guess that could work, still new to Android Development. Thanks